# How do I create a rounded border around my image?

Tags: html, css

I have an image gallery with all images being the same size. I'm trying to add a colored rounded border around the images, however I am having some issue doing so.

For one, the border takes up the entire width of the box, when I only want it to be a bit bigger than the image it's around. Not only that, but it doesn't even cover the entire image, only forming an eclipse around some of it. I used a random image for this, but the same thing happens to all the other images.

```
.galleryStyle {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.galleryContainer {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.galleryGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 3fr);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```
<body class="galleryStyle">
  <div class="galleryGrid">
    <div class="galleryContainer">
      <div>
        <a href="google.com">
          <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BY3PXd2zLT4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image1">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5q9gxof4/1/

Answer (score 3):

The `border-radius` should be applied on the `img` itself.

To do so you can select any `img` tags within the `galleryContainer` div with the following selector and then apply the border radius.

```
.galleryContainer img {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Then you can use the `border` css rule to create a border around your images:

```
.galleryContainer img {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 10px solid red; # This create the border
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
img {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply set border and border-radius directly to your image element like that:

```
img {
  border:10px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and here is a [jsfiddle link for it](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammad408/p65fs2qv/5/)